# Moving files to archive of 1 day old using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want automate the archive process (incl. zip and remove) for the previous day only. I have a script that runs every day and that does the archive but I can set it up only for several days, picking just one day is still a challenge.

I have set a couple of fixed variables (`$archiveyear`, `$archivemonth`, `$archiveday`) that actually let me to archive per day , but this i need to change every day manually.

```
$ArchiveYear = "2018"
$ArchiveMonth = "06"
$ArchiveDay = "06"

$SourcePath = "C:\aa\bb\x"
$TargetPath = "C:\ab"
$YourDirToCompress = "C:\aa\bb\$ArchiveYear\$ArchiveMonth\$ArchiveDay"
$ZipFileResult = "C:\TestDestination\$ArchiveDay$ArchiveMonth.zip"

Get-ChildItem $YourDirToCompress -Directory  | 
    #where { $_.Name -notin $DirToExclude} | 
Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $ZipFileResult -Update
$Days = "1"
$LogPath = "C:\Temp" 
$Date = Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm 
$TargetFolder = "$TargetPath\$Date"
$LogFile = "$LogPath\ArchiveLog-$date.txt"
$TargetZipFile = "$TargetPath\$Date.zip"

$Activity = "Move files older than $Days days from $SourcePath to $TargetFolder"
Write-Verbose $Activity

$OldFiles = Get-Childitem -Path $SourcePath -recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays( - $days)} 
$Total = $Oldfiles.Count
$Current = 0
$OldFiles | ForEach { 
    $Current ++
    $Filename = $_.fullname 
    Write-Progress -Activity $Activity -Status $FileName -PercentComplete ($Current / $Total * 100)    
    $Split = $FileName -split '\\'
    $DestFile = $split[1..($split.Length - 1)] -join '\' 
    $DestFile = "$TargetFolder\$DestFile"

    Try { 
        $null = New-Item -Path  $DestFile -Type File -Force
        $Null = Move-Item -Path  $FileName -Destination $DestFile -Force -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue 
        "Successfully moved $filename to $targetfolder" | add-content $LogFile 
    } 
    Catch { 
        $Err = $_.Exception.Message
        Write-Error $Err
        "Error moving $filename`: $Err " | add-content $LogFile
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you are having?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the question, you want the script to calculate yesterdays date rather than you manually updating `$ArchiveYear` \ `$ArchiveMonth` \ `$ArchiveDay` every time you run\schedule the script?

If so:

```
$Days = "1"
$yesterday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Days)

[string]$ArchiveYear = $yesterday.Year
[string]$ArchiveMonth = $yesterday.Month
[string]$ArchiveDay = $yesterday.Day
```

Comment: Hi thanks,
You understood it correctly, before i test this i had one more quesiton ?

-- $Days = "1" this can remain still like this ? 
"Move files older than $Days days from $SourcePath to $TargetFolder"

Will it be overruled now by ;$yesterday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
and only capture the files from yesterdays day. Or do I need to eliminate this rule

regards,
rchou

Comment: See edit - moved `$Days` to the top and it can be used by the new code too.